# Include banner between files in Grunt

Tags: jquery, gruntjs, grunt-contrib-concat

I would like to concat into a single file

```
plugins.js (out of jQuery function)
fileA.js (jQuery function should start before this file)
fileB.js
...
fileZ.js (jQuery function should end after this file)
```

At the same time I would like to use jsbeautifier in all those files.

How could I add two "banners" before fileA.js

```
jQuery(function($){
```

and after fileZ.js

```
});
```

?

Partial solutions I can think of:

a) Add jQuery(function($){ in fileA.js and fileZ.js the corresponding. This forces me to exclude those two files from jsbeautifier which would throw an error. Also I would have to change the function opening/closing if I change the order of fileA.js,etc

b) Include two files that contain the opening/closing where it corresponds

c) Add "banners" in some similar way as this (I have no clue how to actually do something like this)

```
concat: {
    my_script: {
        files: {
            'myscript.js': [
                'plugins.js',
                // 'jQuery(function($){',
                'fileA.js',
                'fileB.js',
                // ...
                'fileZ.js',
                // '});'
            ],
        },
    },
},
```

Edit: I know for this specific case I can use

```
footer: '})',
```

however it is only a solution to half of the problem

**Is there a better/simplier way of doing this?**

**a) and b) work but I am asking for a simplier way such as c) that I don't know how to achieve.**

Comment: You yourself has given the possible solutions, then, which is the question?

Comment: I don't know much about Grunt. The question is if there is a good/better way of doing this that might be obvious but that I am missing due to my lack of knowledge with Grunt. Thanks

Comment: Please, update your aswer to state that question more clearly.

Answer (score 0):

There are several posibilities, for example:

1. You can use a copy task with a process function that adds the code before and after the original content file: [grunt-contrib-copy process](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-contrib-copy#process)
2. You can also use a combinaion of banner (beginning of the output file), separatos (in between each concatenated file) and footer (bottom of the output file), with 
   [grunt-contrib-concat](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-contrib-concat#separator)
3. You can use [grunt-contrib-concat](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-contrib-concat#separator) with the process option, similtar to 1.

You must take into account in which order are run the tasks. This should be run before the beautifier.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [JotaBe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1216612/jotabe) 's answer I could investigate on [grunt-contrib-copy process](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-contrib-copy#process)
This is the code I finally used.

```
concat: {
    my_script: {
        options: {
            process: function(src, filepath) {
                return src.replace(/\/\/ jQuery\(function\(\$\){/, "jQuery(function($){\n");
            },
            footer: '\n});',
        },
        files: {
            'myscript.js': [
                'plugins.js',
                'fileA.js',
                'fileB.js',
                // ...
                'fileZ.js',
            ],
        },
    },
},
```

fileA.js which is generally the file where I create variables, has to start with the commented-out jQuery enclosure. Basically the "process" from Grunt Concat comments it out. Also I need to include a footer for the closing enclosure (although it could be created in a similar way as the opening).

```
// jQuery(function($){
```